# CNAME to S3 not working

Tags: cname-record, amazon-s3

I have set up a CNAME record to point to an S3 bucket.  It's been up for 4 days, and the results of a DIG Lookup show that it is in place:

```
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;railroad.odehengineers.com.    IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
railroad.odehengineers.com. 3600 IN CNAME   railroad.odeh.s3.amazonaws.com.
railroad.odeh.s3.amazonaws.com. 60 IN   CNAME   s3-directional-w.amazonaws.com.
s3-directional-w.amazonaws.com. 3613 IN CNAME   s3-1-w.amazonaws.com.
s3-1-w.amazonaws.com.   60  IN  A   72.21.203.149
```

I created a test page `test.html` which should be visible from both:

- http://railroad.odeh.s3.amazonaws.com/test.html
- http://railroad.odehengineers.com/test.html

But only the first, direct URL works.  The other gives a 404.

Any thoughts?  Do I need to coordinate at all with Amazon?  Or am I just misunderstanding the purpose of a CNAME record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/index.html?VirtualHosting.html

Comment: I read this briefly before creating the CNAME, but didn't notice the requirement that the S3 bucket must have the same name as the CNAME.  Thanks for pointing me there.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to configure host headers for the site to account for both URL's. Also, it's probably not the best idea to create a CNAME that points to another CNAME.

Comment: What do you mean "configure host headers to account for both URLs"?

Comment: +1, it's a Host Headers (sometimes called Virtual Host) problem, it needs to be fixed on S3. Also, CNAME to a CNAMe isn't so bad, but piling them up will cause noticeable delays eventually.